# Raw value in model state validation is always null in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Here is my custom response model:

```
protected Error GenerateError()
{
    Error error = new Error();
    var details = new List<Detail>();

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        foreach (var key in ModelState.Keys)
        {
            var a = ModelState[key];

            if (ModelState[key].ValidationState == ModelValidationState.Invalid)
            {
                var rawValue = ModelState[key].RawValue;
                var attemptedValue = rawValue != null ? rawValue.ToString() : null;
                var detail = new Detail()
                {
                    Field = key,
                    Value = attemptedValue,
                    Issues = ModelState[key].Errors.Select(o => o.ErrorMessage).ToList()
                };

                details.Add(detail);
            }
        }

        error.Details = details;
    }

    return error;
}
```

Value always returned as null - why?

I am expecting the value I send as the input to be the raw value in the model state.

Comment: How are you passing your model to this method?

Answer (score 0):

> Value always returned as null - why?

It is because you did not define the validated model type in `Error GenerateError()`, causing `ModelState.IsValid` to return true and therefore return a null value. You should define your model validation type for verification. But`[ApiController]` attribute enables model validation errors to automatically trigger [HTTP 400 responses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#automatic-http-400-responses)  , it will return a default BadRequest response.

If you want to customize the error message of model verification, you can try to use a custom action filter to verify the parameters before the method is executed. Here is an example that you can use as a reference:

```
public class CustomModelActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {

        var details = new List<Detail>();
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                foreach (var key in context.ModelState.Keys)
                {
                    if (context.ModelState[key].ValidationState == ModelValidationState.Invalid)
                    {
                        var rawValue = context.ModelState[key].RawValue;
                        var attemptedValue = rawValue != null ? rawValue.ToString() : null;
                        var detail = new Detail()
                        {
                            Field = key,
                            Value = attemptedValue,
                            Issues = context.ModelState[key].Errors.Select(o => o.ErrorMessage).ToList()
                        };

                    details.Add(detail);
                    }
                }
                context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(details)
                {
                    StatusCode = 400 
                };
            }
            
    }
}
```

Register the global model validation filter:

```
options.Filters.Add(new CustomModelActionFilter());
```

Disable system built-in model verification:

```
options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
```

When I send a message that validates incorrect data:
[image]